# Getting date from string in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have to obtain date from a string, here the string will be in format "Monday 02,Dec 2013" i have to convert it to "2013-12-2" .I used the following code but I'm getting wrong output :

```
-(void)dateSelectedInPickerView:(NSString *)dateSelected{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForGettingDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatterForGettingDate setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    // Parse the string representation of the date i.e Monday 2,Dec 2013

    NSDate *dateFromStr = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateSelected];
    NSLog(@"date selected  : %@",dateFromStr);

    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

    self.reservationDateSelected=[tempFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromStr];
    NSLog(@"date Selected : %@",self.reservationDateSelected);
}
```

Comment: NSLog (@"date selected %@",dateFromStr) what it says? NSLog (@"date selected %@",self.reserv..) what it  says? give more info

Comment: `"Monday 2,Dec 2013"` is not even close to match `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: Not the complete solution but be sure to use lowercase `yyyy` instead of uppercase `YYYY`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this, it works for me with `Monday 02,Dec 2013`:

```
-(void)dateSelectedInPickerView:(NSString *)dateSelected{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForGettingDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterForGettingDate setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd,MMM yyyy"];
[dateFormatterForGettingDate setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"]];

// Parse the string representation of the date i.e Monday 2,Dec 2013

NSDate *dateFromStr = [dateFormatterForGettingDate dateFromString:dateSelected];
NSLog(@"date selected  : %@", [dateFromStr descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

self.reservationDateSelected=[tempFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromStr];
NSLog(@"date Selected : %@",self.reservationDateSelected);

}
```

[Read this, if want to know more about Date Format Patterns ;-)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 5):

1) You should use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`. `YYYY` stands for year in "Week of Year" based calendars - it may not always be the same value as calendar year. See the [documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

2) Format to parse "Monday 02,Dec 2013" should be "EEEE dd,MMM yyyy"

EDIT
3) Forget to say about locale — device with non-english locale will fail to parse "Monday 02,Dec 2013" (because of "Monday" and "Dec") if you will not set the locale for the date formatter explicitly:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForGettingDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterForGettingDate.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatterForGettingDate setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd,MMM yyyy"];
```

I think, this should work:

```
-(void)dateSelectedInPickerView:(NSString *)dateSelected{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForGettingDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatterForGettingDate.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatterForGettingDate setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd,MMM yyyy"];

    // Parse the string representation of the date i.e Monday 2,Dec 2013

    NSDate *dateFromStr = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateSelected];
    NSLog(@"date selected  : %@",dateFromStr);

    NSDateFormatter *tempFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [tempFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    self.reservationDateSelected=[tempFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromStr];
    NSLog(@"date Selected : %@",self.reservationDateSelected);
}
```